# what is the difference between parametric and non parametric surface?

Tags: graphics

I am studying texture of computer graphics. Can anyone explain me what is parametric and non parametric surface and what is the difference between these two?

Thanks...

Comment: You might be looking for [Graphic Design SE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).  This site is for programming questions.

Comment: I checked but not found any explanation about that. Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

A parametric surface is defined by equations that generate vertex coordinates as a function of one or more free variables.

In the one-dimensional case it is customary to define parametric curves (e.g. Bezier, Lissajous, or any of several other types) of curves using free variable *t* often defined on the interval [0,1] which can be thought of as a sort of fractional arc length.  An equation is specified which generates each coordinate value as a function of *t*.  As a result, the curve can be rendered to arbitrary precision by evaluating as many vertex points as desired along the defined interval of *t* values.

The alternative is a nonparametric curve which is simply defined as a specific set of vertices which are generally connected with straight lines.  Curves defined nonparametrically don't hold up well to scaling and zooming as eventually the limitations of the defining geometry become apparent.

Parametric surfaces are the higher-dimensional equivalents of parametric curves, where two or more free variables and corresponding functions define the vertices of a mesh.